# Resource.id does not contain a definition or is not found. It fixes by itself then breaks again

Tags: xamarin.android, resources, visual-studio-2019

this is mindf**k. When I am trying to build a project it tells me that Resource.Id does not contain a definition, something like "rootView" or "btn1" and etc. Bet when I am going to the path of the error where it occurred it fixes by itself and error disappears, and this insane loop repeats 1000 times. This is Xamarin.Android project btw.

This is one of the places where I get these errors, there is like 20 of them.

```
            buttonSignin = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.signin_btn);
            buttonSignUp = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.signup_btn);
            email = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.log_email);
            password = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.log_pass);
            rootView = (CoordinatorLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.rootView);
```

That's how they look like. I am not able to post pictures so here is the link to a photo
Give me that REP, then I would be able to post pictures

[image]

Comment: Try to delete the content of the `Resource.Designer.cs` file (delete its content not the file) and rebuild

Comment: Thank you. Actually I found solution on the internet, I forgot to write how I did it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by making a backup of my resources file and deleting it in the project, then I built an app and cleaned it. After that, I put the file into project again and it worked.